# Comma separated value string and compare against other values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, query, parse

Hey all I have been trying to wrap my head around how to go about doing this for a while now and I'm not really coming up with anything.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @ATID AS VARCHAR(3) = 12
DECLARE @AssetID AS VARCHAR(7) = 306

SELECT 
    tblXDataA.AssetID AS 'LID',
    tblA.AssetID AS 'AID',
    tblEM.[Custom] AS 'ABC/S XML',
    tblEMXData.[Custom] AS 'XData XML',
    tblEM.[Custom].value('(/ABCS/text())[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'Parsed XML -> ABCS',
    tblEM.[Custom].value('(/ABC/text())[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'Parsed XML -> ABC',
    tblEMXData.[Custom].value('(/XData/ABC/text())[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'Parsed XML -> XData'
FROM 
    Asset AS tblA 
JOIN 
    LinkStr AS tblL 
        ON tblL.A_AssetID = tblA.AssetID 
JOIN 
    Asset AS tblXDataA 
        ON tblXDataA.AssetID = tblL.B_AssetID 
JOIN
    EMd AS tblEMXData
        ON tblEMXData.AssetID = tblXDataA.AssetID
JOIN 
    EMd AS tblEM 
        ON tblEM.AssetID = tblA.AssetID 
JOIN 
    LinkStr AS tbLinkStrB 
        ON tblXDataA.AssetID = tbLinkStrB.B_AssetID 
WHERE 
    tblXDataA.ATID = @ATID 
AND 
    tblA.AssetID = @AssetID;
```

All of that above produces a few columns of output but the main columns are the **ABCS** and **XData**:

```
LID | AID | Parsed XML -> ABCS                                    | Parsed -> XData                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
481 | 306 | Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,05649880-ED43| Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240
501 | 306 | Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,05649880-ED43| 05649880-ED43
```

The above is correct as-is. There are **2 users** and therefore the **ABCS** has a **comma delimiter** with both **users ABCS**. The first user that is added is the **main** user that all other users go under and therefore it has the **same userID** for **both** [306].

The users **ABCS** are:

> User 1 [main]    : Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240
>
> User 2 [addition]: 05649880-ED43

However, If I delete the last user added **[05649880-ED43]** then **ABCS** should only have **1 users ABCS** in it **instead of 2**. But this is how its turning out:

```
LID | AID | Parsed XML -> ABCS                                    | Parsed -> XData                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
481 | 306 | Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,05649880-ED43| Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240
```

So depending on how many users are added to the **main user** is what I need to check for to make sure those users **who get deleted** are **not** left in the **ABCS** comma string.

Needing to:

> **Get each ABCS comma delimited value and compare it to XData(s)**

So as the example above it would flow like this taken that the database looks like this:

```
LID | AID | Parsed XML -> ABCS                                    | Parsed -> XData                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
481 | 306 | Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,05649880-ED43| Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240
501 | 306 | Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,05649880-ED43| 05649880-ED43
```

> Is **Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240** [ABCS] present in [XData]? answer: **true**
>
> Is **05649880-ED43** [ABCS] present in [XData]? answer: **true**

Since there are **2 users** and **2 rows** then that would, of course, return **both** as **TRUE** and that would be all.

Now If the **added user** gets **deleted** from the **main user**. The table would look like this and which is what currently is happening:

```
LID | AID | Parsed XML -> ABCS                                    | Parsed -> XData                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
481 | 306 | Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,05649880-ED43| Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240
```

> Is **Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240** [ABCS] present in [XData]? answer: **true**
>
> Is **05649880-ED43** [ABCS] present in [XData]? answer: **false**

Since its **true** and **false** then the **false users ABCS ID** needs to be **taken out [DELETED/REMOVED]** of the comma separated string. This is what I am unable to find out how to go about doing.

Help would be great!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend [providing sample data as insert statements and table DDL in the question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Go to dbfiddle, construct a table a few sample records and your desired input. Put the material from the fiddle back here also...

Comment: Go to dbfiddle.uk, construct a table a few sample records and your desired output. Put the material from the fiddle back here also...  help us to help you!

Comment: Why do you need to persist a CSV list (or an XML containing the CSV, for that matter) at a point when the underlying data can still change and thus affect that list? Or why do you want to solve this by modifying the list rather then re-generating the XML based on the changed conditions/circumstances/data?

Comment: @AndriyM Going forward we will implement something that fixes the input to the XML so this isn't an issue any longer. However we have a LOT of records already that are messed up like this and looking for a way of correcting them without having to do it manually.

Comment: @LowlyDBA-JohnM I've tried to create the SQL query online but can not seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the comma-delimited ABCS data into separate rows, then do a full join (if you are looking for ACBS has too many or too few entries) and look for NULL values.  You could do this in-line with your existing query, but it gets messy, so here is how it might look if you dumped your results into a temp table.

Note: I used different AID numbers and some fabricated data for different "test cases"

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Data
CREATE  TABLE #Data(LID INT, AID INT, ABCS NVARCHAR(MAX), XDATA NVARCHAR(MAX))



INSERT INTO #Data VALUES
(481 ,306 ,'Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,05649880-ED43','Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240')
,(501 ,306 ,'Y40GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,05649880-ED43','05649880-ED43')
,(1481 ,1306 ,'140GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,15649880-ED43','140GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240')
,(2481 ,2306 ,'240GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,25649880-ED43','240GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240')
,(2501 ,2306 ,'240GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,25649880-ED43','25649880-ED43')
,(1138 ,2306 ,'240GB4DL4-48302343420105-FH3J-8798-11240,25649880-ED43','8675309-C3P0')


SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(split_acbs.aid, D.aid) AID, c.i.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') acbs , D.xdata
FROM
(SELECT AID, TRY_CAST( '<i>' + REPLACE(ABCS, ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML) codes FROM #DATA) split_acbs
    CROSS APPLY codes.nodes('//i') c(i)
FULL JOIN #data  d ON split_acbs.aid = D.aid AND c.i.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  = D.xdata
WHERE split_acbs.aid IS NULL OR D.aid IS NULL
```

Here is what the results look like:

```
AID         acbs              xdata
----------- ----------------- ------------------
1306        15649880-ED43     NULL
2306        NULL              8675309-C3P0
```